# MFC draw Circle

Tags: c++, mfc

I just started to learn MFC. I need to draw a circle. If I use OnPaint() it works. What should i do that it will draw on background ? Is this the proper function or should I change it?

```
void Cvaja5Dlg::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.Ellipse(0,0,500,500);
    CDialogEx::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [MFC](http://www.relisoft.com/resource/libs.html)?

Comment: i don't want to but i have to for collage. if it would be up to me i would use c#. i actually know how to do that

Comment: You can use CClientDC to do the paining outside OnPaint. It won't persist but will help you draw on every click and will get erased when the background is invalidated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Windows painting works different way. It's quite asynchronous.

1. [`CPaintDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shall be used only inside [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534901%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) handler as it performs `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` calls.
2. All drawing usually shall be performed in overrided [`CWnd::OnPaint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01c9aaty%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[`CView::OnDraw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6htdchf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.
3. On user input (e.g. right mouse button down) your handler shall change state of your class, e.g. set some bool flag `isRightButtonDown` and call [`Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to initiate asynchronous repainting of window. To enforce synch repainting you could use [`UpdateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yz8we9y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [`RedrawWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fdz8ey6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) right after invalidating.

Answer (score 0):

if you want repaint using OnRedraw() method is good...
in that BeginPaint() and endPaint();
using CPAINTDC create the struct of paint handler